# How to share state with other nodes in corda

Tags: corda

Suppose there are 3 nodes: Alice, Bob, Daniel. Normaly if Alice and Bob shares some facts, daniel will not know. So how to share those facts with daniel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Either Alice or Bob can share the state with Daniel. The information sharing on Corda is on the need to know basis. So as long as the original transaction owner decide to share the transaction with any third party, they can.